# Dummy Variables - Can the value of these binary variables be more than 1?

Tags: machine-learning, dummy-variable

I have the following data set:

```
**organization**     **university**
  Facebook             Harvard
  Facebook             Harvard
  Facebook             Harvard
  Wetpaint             UC Berkeley
  Wetpaint             LSE
```

These are the universities attended by the founders & co-founders of these organizations. For my machine learning project (using Random Forest & Decision Trees) I would like to have 1 row for each organization. I believe I could easily do this by creating dummy variables where they would have a 1 for the existence of an organization and 0 otherwise.

After creating the dummy variables would it be possible to add up the dummy variables and merge the rows. Below is the result I expect:

```
**organization**  **Harvard**  **UC Berkeley**  **LSE**
Facebook               3              0            0
Wetpaint               0              1            1
```

I am wondering if this technically makes sense for the machine learning algorithms. I also think that since we have 3 rows for Facebook and only 2 rows for Wetpaint that also causes an imbalance in the rows. Wondering if that would also cause additional issues.

Alternatively is it ok to have repeated rows for each organization and just run the algorithm? Would that cause any issues?

Please let me know. Please leave a reference to a relevant book or scientific journal.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your required output simply use pandas `cross tab`

```
>>> data = {'organization':['Facebook','Facebook','Facebook','Wetpaint','Wetpaint'], 'university':['Harvard','Harvard','Harvard','UCBerveley','LSE']}
>>> df = pd.datframe(data=data)

>>> df
  organization  university
0     Facebook     Harvard
1     Facebook     Harvard
2     Facebook     Harvard
3     Wetpaint  UCBerveley
4     Wetpaint         LSE

#use crosstab

>>> df_new = pd.crosstab(df.organization, df.university).reset_index()
>>> df_new
university organization  Harvard  LSE  UCBerveley
0              Facebook        3    0           0
1              Wetpaint        0    1           1
```

To the rest of you machine learning question: There is no thumb rule as to which is the best way to preprocess a dataset, it completely depends on your use case and how big and diverse data you are using. For example: in the above question instead of getting count for each university in all separate columns where you have the problem of `0's` coming for other universities you can use it in this way as well where based on `organisation` and `university` it will give you the count of just the individuals present so no `0's`

```
>>> df.groupby(['organization','university'])['university'].count()
organization  university
Facebook      Harvard       3
Wetpaint      LSE           1
              UCBerveley    1
```

But however as said earlier it completely depends on your requirement, use case and dataset. There are tons on material on internet on how to pre-process data for a given scenario, you can check them and gauge which best suits your needs